# Android Image Caching For Bitmaps

Tags: android

HI i was implementing image Caching in Android.
Have gone thorough this

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

```
public class ImageCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> {

  public ImageCache( int maxSize ) {
    super( maxSize );
  }

  @Override
  protected int sizeOf( String key, Bitmap value ) {
    return value.getByteCount();
  }

  @Override
  protected void entryRemoved( boolean evicted, String key, Bitmap oldValue, Bitmap newValue ) {
    oldValue.recycle();
  }

}
```

what criteria i want to keep is that whenever there is a url mismatch the image should be downloaded from server else it should keep that in local cachle which will be available all time even when the app is not working.

now what i have tried is to put them in hashmap but it does not returns anything when their is url mismatch.