# Convert android.net.Uri to java.net.URL

Tags: java, android

I used code from [CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060979/android-image-caching-for-bitmaps/%22CODE%22) and I want to use images from my drawables folder, however the code requires a URL.

I tried to do:

```
 android.net.Uri aURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet" + R.drawable.icon_bar);
    try {
        java.net.URI jURI = new java.net.URI(aURI.toString());
        URL url =  jURI.toURL();
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(url.getPath(), loader, iconBar_View);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However it didn't load the image. What can fix this?

Log

> 04-20 13:23:04.176    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: android.resource
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.176    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.(URL.java:182)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.176    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.(URL.java:125)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.176    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1378)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.176    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:142)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.176    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.176    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.177    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.178    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>
> 04-20 13:23:04.178    2458-2458/com.kapsapetapp.kapsapet W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: You want to set a drawable from your application and set to an imageView in your application, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show image from drawables no need to use `java.net.URI` . do it as:

```
Uri uriImage = Uri.parse("drawable://" + R.drawable.icon_bar);  
imgLoader.DisplayImage(String.valueOf(uriImage), loader, iconBar_View);
```

Comment: Sorry, finger slipped and didn't notice